# how to make a data group after every certain value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a set of data that has value -1000 when the sensor is on standby.
Numbers of -1000 depends on time passed and different every time.
I want to make a group of data that is between every -1000.
To be specific, I want to get an average of the data and write it to E.
Is there a way to do that with pandas or any library?
Thanks in advance.

Raw Data

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1000 | -1000 | -1000 | -1000 |  |
| -1000 | -1000 | -1000 | -1000 |  |
| -1000 | -1000 | -1000 | -1000 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |  |
| 7 | 10 | 5 | 6 |  |
| -1000 | -1000 | -1000 | -1000 |  |
| 3 | 5 | 9 | 9 |  |
| 1 | 11 | 2 | 10 |  |
| -1000 | -1000 | -1000 | -1000 |  |
| -1000 | -1000 | -1000 | -1000 |  |

.
.
.

Data I wish to get after processing

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1000 | -1000 | -1000 | -1000 | 4.75 |
| -1000 | -1000 | -1000 | -1000 | 6.25 |
| -1000 | -1000 | -1000 | -1000 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |  |
| 7 | 10 | 5 | 6 |  |
| -1000 | -1000 | -1000 | -1000 |  |
| 3 | 5 | 9 | 9 |  |
| 1 | 11 | 2 | 10 |  |
| -1000 | -1000 | -1000 | -1000 |  |
| -1000 | -1000 | -1000 | -1000 |  |

.
.
.
edit 1
Raw data 1

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1000 | -1000 | -1000 | -1000 | 4.75 |
| -1000 | 5 | -1000 | -1000 | 6.25 |
| -1000 | -1000 | 8 | -1000 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |  |
| 7 | 10 | 5 | 6 |  |
| -1000 | -1000 | -1000 | -1000 |  |
| 3 | 5 | 9 | 9 |  |
| 1 | 11 | 2 | 10 |  |
| -1000 | -1000 | -1000 | -1000 |  |
| -1000 | -1000 | -1000 | -1000 |  |

sometimes there are col contains positive value while others are -1000.
is there anyway to get average only when all values are positive?

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
cond = df['A'].eq(-1000)
grp = cond.cumsum() 
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

out = (df[~cond]
       .groupby(grp)[cols].mean()
       .mean(axis=1)
       .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

out:

```
0    4.75
1    6.25
dtype: float64
```

if you want make `out` to E column

```
df['E'] = out
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'A': [-1000, -1000, -1000, 1, 7, -1000, 3, 1, -1000, -1000],
         'B': [-1000, -1000, -1000, 2, 10, -1000, 5, 11, -1000, -1000],
         'C': [-1000, -1000, -1000, 3, 5, -1000, 9, 2, -1000, -1000],
         'D': [-1000, -1000, -1000, 4, 6, -1000, 9, 10, -1000, -1000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast responds!

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
mask = df["A"].eq(-1000)
vals = (
    df[~mask].groupby((mask != mask.shift()).cumsum()).apply(lambda x: x.mean().mean())
)

df["E"] = np.pad(vals, (0, len(df) - len(vals)), constant_values=np.nan)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      A     B     C     D     E
0 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000  4.75
1 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000  6.25
2 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000   NaN
3     1     2     3     4   NaN
4     7    10     5     6   NaN
5 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000   NaN
6     3     5     9     9   NaN
7     1    11     2    10   NaN
8 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000   NaN
9 -1000 -1000 -1000 -1000   NaN
```